# Android SQLite query has question mark in selector and null in selectionArgs

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In android if I call the SQLiteDatabase method query like the following:

```
sqlitedb.query("mytable", null, "name = ?",
     new String[] {null}, null, null, null);
```

What is the expected result?

I would expect a `NullPointerException` but it seems like I am getting a cursor back that seems to have the same data as the last non-null selectionArgs query I performed. Is this expected behavior, I guess I have to do my own null checking before calling this method and instead pass "name IS NULL" to get the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with NPE @satur9nine.  It has to do with SQL argument procressing.  I've verified that you are correct.  With SQLite, if you issue:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable ` WHERE `name` = ?
```

with a null argument across a table which has rows with null `name` fields, you will get no results.  You are going to have to issue the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable ` WHERE `name` IS NULL
```

This is not just Android but also JDBC.  It is a database issue.  SQLite, H2, and MySQL all behave this way.  From this great SQL tutorial:

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

To quote:

> It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>.

Answer (score 0):

In java if I do:

```
  String test1 = "";
  String test2 = null;
  bool result = test1.equals(test2);
```

result will be set false. No NullPointerException occurs. This is probably what is happening. In order to avoid this behavior you should, as you suggested in your question, make sure to check that your name string isn't null.

Comment: Uh, this has nothing to do withit @Kurtis.  He's talking about SQL and SQLite arguments.

Comment: @Gray I think your mistaken. What I postulate in my answer is that no null pointer exception occurs because in java comparing a "" and a null string is valid. He specifically asks in his question "why no null pointer exception". How does that not address what he's talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  The _answer_ is not about Java object testing but about SQL argument processing and null value handling.

Comment: @Gray Ah, well feel free to disagree with my answer and (as you have done) provide your own.