# How to bind INTEGER/NULL to a ? placeholder with rawQuery selectionArgs in Android?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, sql-injection

***Anything can change below to reach a working solution!*** I have full control over all of the below schema/data/query/code, so any reasonable improvement is welcome: I'm looking for a simple/clean/to-the-point solution. For example making two different queries (`= ?` and `is null`) is the **last resort**.

#### Question

I want to change the below code so I can call `listCategoriesIn(1)` and `listCategoriesIn(null)` and they both give the correct expected result.
I can't make `listCategoriesIn(null)` work with a `WHERE` clause like `c.parent = ?`.

- Is it at all possible to bind an `INTEGER` or `NULL` to `= ?`?
- How should I modify the `WHERE` clause to make it work for both cases?
- What else may I change to make it work?

#### Table

```
CREATE TABLE Category (
    _id         INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR      NOT NULL,
    parent      INTEGER          NULL --< important bit
        CONSTRAINT fk_Category_parent
            REFERENCES Category(_id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(_id AUTOINCREMENT),
    UNIQUE(name)
);
```

#### Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO Category
                  (_id, parent, name)
          SELECT     0,   NULL, 'cat0'         --< expected for listCategoriesIn(null)
    UNION SELECT     1,   NULL, 'cat1'         --< expected for listCategoriesIn(null)
    UNION SELECT    11,      1,   'cat1-1'     --< expected for listCategoriesIn(1)
    UNION SELECT    12,      1,   'cat1-2'     --< expected for listCategoriesIn(1)
    UNION SELECT   121,     12,     'cat1-2-1'
    UNION SELECT   122,     12,     'cat1-2-2'
    UNION SELECT    13,      1,   'cat1-3'     --< expected for listCategoriesIn(1)
    UNION SELECT   131,     13,     'cat1-3-1'
    UNION SELECT     2,   NULL, 'cat2'         --< expected for listCategoriesIn(null)
    UNION SELECT    21,      2,   'cat2-1'
    UNION SELECT     3,   NULL, 'cat3'         --< expected for listCategoriesIn(null)
;
```

#### Query

*IRL I'm using much more complex ones involving views, sub-queries, multiple JOINs.*

```
select
    c.*,
    (select count() from Category where parent = c._id) as count
from Category c
where c.parent = ? --< important bit
;
```

#### Wrong Code #1

```
public Cursor listCategoriesIn(SQLiteDatabase db, Long categoryID) {
    // public Cursor SQLiteDatabse.rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs);
    return db.rawQuery(CATEGORY_QUERY, new String[] {
        String.valueOf(categoryID)
    });
}
```

> `listCategoriesIn(1)`: works OK
>
> `listCategoriesIn(null)`: the resulting Cursor is empty, possibly `= 'null'` or `= NULL` is bound.

#### Wrong Code #2

```
public Cursor listCategoriesIn(SQLiteDatabase db, Long categoryID) {
    // public Cursor SQLiteDatabse.rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs);
    return db.rawQuery(CATEGORY_QUERY, new String[] {
        categoryID == null? null : categoryID.toString()
    });
}
```

> `listCategoriesIn(1)`: works OK
>
> `listCategoriesIn(null)`:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sleeping on it and starting a new day I had an epiphany, it's possible without duplication of the query:

```
where c.parent = ? or (? = 'null' and c.parent is null)
```

However we need to duplicate the argument, here's the corresponding Java call:

```
public Cursor listCategoriesIn(SQLiteDatabase db, Long categoryID) {
    return db.rawQuery(CATEGORY_QUERY, new String[] {
        String.valueOf(categoryID), String.valueOf(categoryID)
    });
}
```

There's no NPE when `categoryID` is `null`, because it binds as `"null"` (see `valueOf`). Passing `null->'null'` to the driver activates the second part of the `WHERE` clause, and of course none of the `INTEGER` values will be `= 'null'` so the first part doesn't play.

This trick works because [`rawQuery` binds everything as `String`s](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) and the SQLite engine can handle comparing `INTEGER`s with numbers in a `TEXT`. I'm sure the details can be found in the [SQLite Datatypes documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send a different SQL statement when a field is NULL.

```
    public Cursor listCategoriesIn(SQLiteDatabase db, Long categoryID) {
        if(categoryID == null)
            return db.rawQuery(CATEGORY_QUERY_NULL, null);
        else
            return db.rawQuery(CATEGORY_QUERY, new String[] { categoryID.toString() });
   }
```

where CATEGORY_QUERY_NULL is the same query as CATEGORY_QUERY but with `c.parent IS NULL` instead of `c.parent = ?`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7870529/1270276) for details.

Comment: Yep, this is the last resort I was talking about... I hope someone may have a more clever solution as I'd rather not duplicate complex SQL queries.

Comment: `categoryID == null` is always false in your second branch. You can replace the entire statement with `return db.rawQuery(CATEGORY_QUERY, new String[] { categoryID.toString() });`

Comment: I'm against duplication, because if you consider having 3 of these nullable columns in one `WHERE`, it would explode to `2^3=8` queries -> unmaintainable. The solution I found can be combined linearly, though a little tricky.